# Calling C# Web Service from JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, wcf

I have a JSON web service set up in C#, and I'm trying to create a custom HTML page to call it.

```
http://localhost:25524/DBService.svc/json/db=TestDB/query=none
```

I enter that in my browser and try get JSON formatted data back. The data is a dictionary, with a Key and Value, but it doesn't show up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello jQuery</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="app-key">The ID is </p>
            <p class="app-value">The content is </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hello.Js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:25524/DBService.svc/json/db=TestDB/query=none"
    }).then(function(data) {
    alert(data);
       $('.app-key').append(data.JobId);
       $('.app-value').append(data.RunTime);
    });
});
```

Service Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "json/db={inDatabase_}/query={inQuery_}")]
    DBResult GetData(string inDatabase_, string inQuery_);
```

The data being returned comes back in this format

```
{
    "GetDataResult": {
        "DataSet": [],
        "DataSize": 0,
        "Fault": null,
        "JobId": "64ba7350-49e1-47f5-9d81-c623fdff141d",
        "RunTime": 34554
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I need to know how to consume it, that's the way i tried but its not working

Comment: What is the format of the JSON being returned?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan {"GetDataResult":{"DataSet":[],"DataSize":0,"Fault":null,"JobId":"64ba7350-49e1-47f5-9d81-c623fdff141d","RunTime":34554}}

Comment: how the dbresult type look like?

Comment: Which values are you trying to put in to your HTML? `key` and `value` do not exist.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan datasize and runtime and jobid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `datasize`, `runtime` and `jobid` values as mentioned in your comments, you first need to add some elements in your HTML to show the values:

```
<div>
    <p class="app-datasize">The datasize is </p>
    <p class="app-runtime">The runtime is </p>
    <p class="app-jobid">The job id is </p>
</div>
```

Then update your JS to retrieve those values from the received JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:25524/DBService.svc/json/db=TestDB/query=none"
}).then(function(data) {
   $('.app-datasize').append(data.GetDataResult.DataSize);
   $('.app-runtime').append(data.GetDataResult.RunTime);
   $('.app-jobid').append(data.GetDataResult.JobId);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this simple code will help you:

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "your service url", 
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },   
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }  
})  
  .done(function( result) {  
    alert( "Data Saved: " + result.GetDataResult );  
  });
```